# jenn air JJW8330DDS terminal block melted/ keypad not working

Tags: electrical, oven

My wall oven stopped working and based on consulting with a friend who is a hardware engineer, we decided that the control board might have fried. The only keypad buttons that responded to touch were the cancel, #3, #6, #9 and oven light. The #3, #6 and #9 buttons would beep twice when the touched. The cancel button would beep once and the oven light button would turn the oven light, but would not turn it off immediately. You had to touch the oven light again hours later to turn off the light.

I installed a refurbished control board that board gave me the same results when I touched the keypad. Cancel, #3, #6, #9 and the oven light were the only buttons that did anything.

So, I decided the control board was not the problem and looked at the oven more thoroughly. I saw that one of the connections on the block terminal had burned up as well the red wires that were connected to the terminal block. I sent back the control board and ordered a new wiring harness. The wiring harness included the block terminal and all wiring that would be connected it other than the leads from the home outlet. I expected this would fix my issues.

After installing the wiring harness, I turned the power back on and the keypad is still doing the same thing it was before.

Any ideas on what might be going on here? I would like to fix it myself, but at this point I am loosing credibility with the Mrs. and I don't have a clear next step other than calling a repairman.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you changing the actual control board, or the keypad assembly?

Comment: I changed the control board but not the keypad. I did have the thought after I posted my question that the keypad might need to be changed. Is that where you were headed? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this problem occurs with multiple control boards -- it may be the keypad itself that's dead.  Try replacing the keypad and seeing if that fixes it.

Comment: The keypad has been ordered. I will update on the results in a few days. Thanks

Comment: @Brad_A_Tx_:   .... and?